# Can Pine script call back outside Api?

Tags: pine-script

I want to use Pine script to build a strategy in Tradingview website, and use outside data.
Can Pine script call back outside Api?

Comment: I suggest you read its documents carefully and doing some effort, then in case of having any problems, you can share your code here so the experts can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could elaborate on what you mean on "call back outside Api"? Of course you can use Pine Script to create an `alertcondition` putting POST data in JSON format in the `message` argument and sending it to a webhook URL.

Answer (score 2):

Simple No! You cant make Api call directly,  you can use alert which triggers webhook that you catch and forward to the Api you wanted.
But remember webhook is only available in paid version.